# Angling entire cell in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

[image][image]

I'm trying to make a table where the entire header column is at an angle -- not just the text, but the cell itself. I've found the code for angling the text, but nothing that would angle the cell itself. Below is the code I'm starting with:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Long_Column_Name = 1:5,
  Different_Column_Name= 5:9,
  Third_Column_Name = 10:14
)

df %>%
  kable(align='c',linesep='') %>%
  row_spec(0,angle=45) %>%
  column_spec(1,background='#CCCCFF',include_thead=TRUE)
```

Attached images shows what's produced from this code compared with an approximation of the output I want; the text in the headers is angled, but the cells are still rectangular and matching the rows below. Ideally the cells in the row would themselves be angled at 45 degrees to match the text. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you rephrase "but the cell itself"? If you add `row_spec(0,angle=45, background='#CCCCFF')` you see that not only the text rotates, but perhaps I simply do not understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: Sure --  edited to attach image of what I've got from the code I have - the cells are still square, with the height changed to fit the angled text. Adding the code you gave only adds background to the other cells in the top row, without changing the shape of the cells. I'm hoping for non-rectangular angled cells rather than rectangular cells.

Comment: with html output it works with `row_spec(0,angle=45, background='#CCCCFF')` but indeed in pdf it seems to work differently.

Comment: Interesting - I'm not actually getting this code to compile at all with html_document. I get the message:
Error in UseMethod("nodeset_apply"): no applicable method for 'nodeset_apply' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: Try it with `include_thead=FALSE`

Comment: That will run, but it also causes the angled text to run into the row below it - and, removing the include_thead adds the problem of the header cell not having the background color.